# Assign new values for columns in data frame from a random row in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, say df1 and df2. I want to randomly sample a row from df2 and assign some of the columns from this row to a row in df1. Here is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
print(df1)
  col1
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
```

And,

```
d2 = {'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col3': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 'col4':['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'] }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
print(df2)
  col2 col3 col4
0    a    e    i
1    b    f    j
2    c    g    k
3    d    h    l
```

I want to randomly sample a row from df2 and assign col2 and col4 to new columns in df1. So, the results should look something like this:

```
   col1 col2 col4
0     1    b    j
1     2    d    l
2     3    a    i
3     4    c    k
```

So, I iterate over the rows in df1, sample a row from df2 and assign some of the columns in this row in df2 to new columns in df1. The new values in each row in df1 are all from the same row in df2.
I tried to use assign and lambda function but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, if you need to copy col2 and col4 to df1(after shuffled), just do

```
df1.loc[: ["col2", "col4"]] = df2[["col2", "col4"]].sample(n=4)
```

but make sure their length are same

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

First, randomly sample the indices of the df2 rows

```
random_sampled = random.sample(range(len(df2)), len(df1))
```

Then, create new columns in df1 and assign values from df2

```
df1[['col2', 'col4']] = df2.iloc[random_sampled][['col2', 'col4']].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1)
```